# Joining same table getting duplicate rows for some ID

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
I have a table test 

ID       Status     

1       A     
1       C     
2       A   
3       A   
4       A  
4       C  
4       A  
4       C  
5       A


Desire Output

ID      Status  
1       A   
1       C     
4       A   
4       C   
4       A   
4       C
```

`
    I tried this

```
 select * from test 
join
    (
        select id from test t
        where status='c'
    ) b
on b.id=test.id
```

It works fine for ID=1 wherein it gives me 2 row, but for id=4 it gives me 8 rows I don't know what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only issue with your query is that the subquery currently will return *multiple* IDs having the C status.  One option here is to use `GROUP BY ID` in the subquery to restrict each ID to appear only once.

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.Status
FROM test t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ID
    FROM test
    WHERE Status = 'C'
    GROUP BY ID
) t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.ID
```

Comment: Hi TIm I am getting 6 rows for some ID, wherein in DB there is only 4

Comment: @RedDevil I get your desired output when I run this query locally.  You must have some other problem with your data.

Answer (score 1):

You get 8 rows, because your ID 4 has more 'Cs' then just 1

If you just run

```
    select id from test t
    where status='c'
```

You will get

```
    1, 4, 4
```

As result

So in your inner select try with

```
    select DISTINCT id from test t
    where status='c'
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to go for desired output then try using count:

```
 SELECT 
    t1.ID, t1.Status
 FROM 
    test t1
 GROUP BY
    t1.ID, t1.Status
 Having
    COUNT(t1.ID) > 1
```

Comment: The requirement is a count of 'C' being one or greater, not any ID having a count of two or greater (again, not my downvote).

Answer (score -1):

If you use count in your inner SELECT you do not need to filter for any specific Status:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.Status
FROM [test] t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ID
    FROM [test]
    GROUP BY ID
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.ID
```

Comment: I'm not sure the OP wants this, and besides your query is a cut-and-paste copy of my answer (not my downvote).

Comment: Cut and Paste yes. But from the question ;)